# bundle install failing with errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, centos, rvm, bundle-install

I run bundle install from the cli this is what I get.

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:89:in `run': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Ext::BuildError)

    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-sqlite3-include=/usr/local/include --with-sqlite3-lib=/usr/local/lib
checking for main() in -lc... yes
creating Makefile

make  clean

make
compiling http11.c
http11.c: In function ‘http_field’:
http11.c:77: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
http11.c:77: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘len’
http11.c:77: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect
http11.c: In function ‘header_done’:
http11.c:172: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
http11.c:172: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
http11.c:172: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
http11.c:174: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
http11.c:176: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
http11.c:177: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘len’
http11.c: In function ‘HttpParser_execute’:
http11.c:298: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
http11.c:299: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘len’
make: *** [http11.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/bomnipot/ruby/gems/gems/mongrel-1.1.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/bomnipot/ruby/gems/extensions/x86_64-linux/1.9.1/mongrel-1.1.5/gem_make.out
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:51:in `block in make'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:43:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:43:in `make'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:47:in `block in build'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tempfile.rb:320:in `open'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:17:in `build'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:161:in `block (2 levels) in build_extension'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:160:in `chdir'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:160:in `block in build_extension'
        from <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in `build_extension'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:198:in `block in build_extensions'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `build_extensions'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1436:in `block in build_extensions'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:45:in `use_ui'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1434:in `build_extensions'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:60:in `build_extensions'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:56:in `contains_requirable_file?'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:925:in `block in find_inactive_by_path'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find_inactive_by_path'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:185:in `try_activate'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:132:in `rescue in require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:9:in `<main>'

The path:
env | grep -iE 'ruby|rvm|gem' | sort
GEM_CACHE=/home/bomnipot/ruby/gems/cache
GEM_HOME=/home/bomnipot/ruby/gems
GEM_PATH=/home/bomnipot/ruby/gems:/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.3
 if rvm_pretty_print stderr; then
IRBRC=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/.irbrc
MY_RUBY_HOME=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547
PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin:/home/bomnipot/perl5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/home/bomnipot/ruby/gems/bin:/home/bomnipot/ruby/gems:/home/bomnipot/bin
 printf "%b" "${rvm_debug_clr:-}$*${rvm_reset_clr:-}\n";
RUBY_VERSION=ruby-1.9.3-p547
rvm_bin_path=/usr/local/rvm/bin
rvm_debug=() {  (( ${rvm_debug_flag:-0} )) || return 0;
rvm_delete_flag=0
rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm
rvm_prefix=/usr/local
rvm_version=1.25.30 (stable)
```

I am sure I am missing something. I have not been able to get it to work.

I have googled many help articles to figure out what is going on. Install, removed, and installed again rvm, ruby, rails, and such. Upgrading and down grading gems.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: It was working until I broke it. I don't recall what I did to break it.

Comment: This is a bluehost VPS system. Most of the set up was done using install scripts provided by bluehost.

Comment: change your gemfile from mongrel to thin, do you know what I mean?

Comment: see https://www.google.com.co/search?q=struct+RString%E2%80%99+has+no+member+named+%E2%80%98ptr, first two results

Comment: Running any bundle command seems to provide the same results.

Comment: show what you did in your gemfile, please

Comment: Running gem update --system at root solved the problem.

Comment: @masterartisan feel free to post your solution as an answer, and accept it.